# iOS equivalent of Android's onPageFinished?

Tags: ios, backbone.js, webview

I tried `webViewDidFinishLoad` but it's quite not the same.

On Android, when I move to different page using backbone navigate, `onPageFinished` fires.

But iOS's `webViewDidFinishLoad` doesn't.

Comment: Have you set the UIWebViewDelegate? webViewDidFinishLoad  is a delegate method and you need to set your webviews delegate to make it work.

Comment: And what is the difference? I've just read documentation and both look absolutely similar.

Comment: @Vaionixx oh yes, I did. webViewDidFinishLoad gets called when request is made to server (page refresh). I guess key term here's Backbone's navigate. I use it in my little SPA , so this doesn't trigger the page refresh.

Comment: sry I missed the Backbone part. I hade the same problem with a Sencha Touch SPA. The webViewDidFinishLoad just got called once. I can't find my code to see if and how I resolved it.

Comment: @eugeneDid you get any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AnandGautam sorry it was so long time ago :(

Comment: No problem, appreciate your response @eugene